# Check if PIP is active

Tags: android, picture-in-picture

I have an app that runs foreground service. Is there any way to check if there are any PiP's currently active when:

1. I'm in my app and pip is overlaying it
2. I'm in launcher and pip is active

If so, is it also possible to interact with them in any way, like closing when I enter my app or even get their position on screen?

Answer (score 0):

Activity has a method for that. Check out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#isInPictureInPictureMode()

```
public boolean isInPictureInPictureMode ()
```

> Returns true if the activity is currently in picture-in-picture mode.

Comment: This isn't useful for determining if other apps are currently in Picture in Picture, only your own.